# Can i use a String to call methods in java?

Tags: java

I want to be able to call myMethod() by using Function. in my code i have a long list of available functions and would like the user to pick one without an if then system. any help?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Function = "myMethod";
    Function();
    }
```

Comment: why not just test for the condition and call the method if it matches the criteria you specified

Comment: Lol.. You expect "String" to be callable? Alternatively the only thing I can think of is to use that string to find the function in the current class and call it via reflection.

Comment: You can, if you use reflection, but you probably shouldn't.  It's often easier to store strings and methods in a `Map` and use that to bind the two.

Comment: @JohnKane What do you mean?

Comment: @Nimrod Rappaport for example: if(methodName.equals("runSomething"))Object.runSomething;

Comment: You could also use the command pattern  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200427/4645510

Comment: Functors may be a better solution.